# How to fix InstallException/ShellCommandUnresponsiveException?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-emulator, maven-3

When I try to deploy my application to Android emulator using `mvn android:deploy` I often get following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:deploy 
(default-cli) on project ccp-android: Install of D:\myproject\target\myproject.apk failed. 
InstallException: ShellCommandUnresponsiveException -> [Help 1]
```

How can I fix this (except options listed below) ?

**Known answers:**

1. Buy a more powerful notebook.
2. Buy use a real Android device for development (instead of the emulator).
3. Restart `adb` (run commands `adb kill-server`, `adb start-server`, `mvn android:emulator-start`).
4. Restart the emulator.
5. Try to use a different emulator (like one based on VirtualBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using [AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/) instead of the normal emulator.